# Creating a multilingual app in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

My application is made only in English and i want to switch it to multilingual version . But instead of user changing default language in regionaal settings i gave my application a "ToolStripMenuItem" called langauge and added a submenu for Arabic , Korean and English version .

As far i am aware three things are required -:

1. Writing a code in click event of that Langauage subemenu say "Arabic"
2. Creating a corresponding resx file
3. Also i had set the Form localizable property to "True"

This is the code i added to my Program in Form1()

```
//this variable indicates the current language in use
    CultureInfo CurrentLocale;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        valueInit();
        //MessageBox.Show(rfidCard.PORT + "");
    }


    //Lets start adding the multilingual code here




    //change the language in real time 
    private void ChangeLanguage(string lang)
    {
        CurrentLocale = new CultureInfo(lang);
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            resources.ApplyResources(c, "$this");
            RefreshResources(this, resources);
        }
    }

    //refresh all the controls e sub-controls of the form 
    private void RefreshResources(Control ctrl, ComponentResourceManager res)
    {
        ctrl.SuspendLayout();
        res.ApplyResources(ctrl, ctrl.Name, CurrentLocale);
        foreach (Control control in ctrl.Controls)
            RefreshResources(control, res); // recursion
        ctrl.ResumeLayout(false);
    }

    private void englishToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeLanguage("en-US");
    }

    private void arabicToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeLanguage("ar-SA");
    }

    private void koreanToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeLanguage("ko-KR");
    }

    // the code ends here
```

Second i added a resx file called Form1.ar-SA.resx and inside that just for testing added two things :

$this.Text =    Abc M البرمجيات تطبيق ويب

> > $this.Name =  Form1

However when i run my application and try clicking on language Arabic it still does not change anything .

can someone please help me to find where i went wrong or what am i missing ?

Also in the default.resx i found another column saying

> > $this.Type = System.Windows.Forms.Form, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Does that make any difference ?

EDIT1 : While browsing i found i also need to have  genaerated a designer.cs file cprresponding to it . The search engines talked about having some "RazorGenerator" installed  . I tried installing it from the package manager but it failed . Any light on this please

EDIT2 : Here is what I did . I created the two additional .resx files one for Korean and another for Arabic and tried changing language of form  and it worked great in the coding view. However something is still missing . Firstly I am still not able to change the language by clicking on the tool strip language option as desired . Secondly I even tried to change the locale of my system to Korean but the application picks up no change . Its always displayed in English

Answer (score 0):

You should use system.globalization for this matter, and you don't have to create resource file, just change language in your form and start editing c# do it for you,  but why it don't affect?!

BECAUSE, c# do it after you reset your application, what you should do is save data about your application state, and restart your application after that reload it with desired localization. If you don't wanna do that don't use globalization, set whole ui like by line, 
Sry that in my state (I'm in bus) can't give you the exact code, but it's how you should do it, Application.Restart() I think or some thing close by

Comment: :Thanks for your advice .Here is what I did . I created the two additional resx files one for Korean and another for Arabic and tried changing language of form like you advised and it worked great . However something is still missing . Firstly I am still not able to change the language by clicking on the tool strip language option as desired . Secondly I even tried to change the locale of my system to Korean but the application picks up no change .

Comment: Yah you can't do that as you wish, but about the other thing I think there was a localization class that told you which localization user has on his system,  if you didn't find leave me a msg, and I check out tonight,  it's 1 o'clock here,  and I'll back at 6... Cya

Comment: Sry had headache last night,  I'm not sure but I think it was the code which you should do at begin: system.threading.thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCalture= system.globalization.CaltureInfo("en-CA");   I didn't find the other code in whole my book,also there was another thing to do too, you can store all your resources in separate empty project,  once you need specific resource, then load that specific assembly, but my self I never done that and there were no brief explanation